# Code not actually asserting in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby and in various open source software I've noticed a number of "statements" in some RSpec descriptions that appear not to accomplish what they intended, like they wanted to make an assertion, but didn't.  Are these coding errors or is there some RSpec or Ruby magic I'm missing?  (Likelihood of weirdly overloaded operators?)

The examples, with #??? added to the suspect lines:

(rubinius/spec/ruby/core/array/permutation_spec.rb)

```
it "returns no permutations when the given length has no permutations" do
  @numbers.permutation(9).entries.size == 0        #???
  @numbers.permutation(9) { |n| @yielded << n }
  @yielded.should == []
end
```

(discourse/spec/models/topic_link_spec.rb)

```
it 'works' do
  # ensure other_topic has a post
  post

  url = "http://#{test_uri.host}/t/#{other_topic.slug}/#{other_topic.id}"

  topic.posts.create(user: user, raw: 'initial post')
  linked_post = topic.posts.create(user: user, raw: "Link to another topic: #{url}")

  TopicLink.extract_from(linked_post)

  link = topic.topic_links.first
  expect(link).to be_present
  expect(link).to be_internal
  expect(link.url).to eq(url)
  expect(link.domain).to eq(test_uri.host)

  link.link_topic_id == other_topic.id       #???
  expect(link).not_to be_reflection

  ...
```

(chef/spec/unit/chef_fs/parallelizer.rb)

```
context "With :ordered => false (unordered output)" do
  it "An empty input produces an empty output" do
    parallelize([], :ordered => false) do
      sleep 10
    end.to_a == []                        #???
    expect(elapsed_time).to be < 0.1
  end
```

(bosh/spec/external/aws_bootstrap_spec.rb)

```
it "configures ELBs" do
  load_balancer = elb.load_balancers.detect { |lb| lb.name == "cfrouter" }
  expect(load_balancer).not_to be_nil
  expect(load_balancer.subnets.sort {|s1, s2| s1.id <=> s2.id }).to eq([cf_elb1_subnet, cf_elb2_subnet].sort {|s1, s2| s1.id <=> s2.id })
  expect(load_balancer.security_groups.map(&:name)).to eq(["web"])

  config = Bosh::AwsCliPlugin::AwsConfig.new(aws_configuration_template)
  hosted_zone = route53.hosted_zones.detect { |zone| zone.name == "#{config.vpc_generated_domain}." }
  record_set = hosted_zone.resource_record_sets["\\052.#{config.vpc_generated_domain}.", 'CNAME'] # E.g. "*.midway.cf-app.com."
  expect(record_set).not_to be_nil
  record_set.resource_records.first[:value] == load_balancer.dns_name   #???
  expect(record_set.ttl).to eq(60)
end
```

Comment: Hard to determine what is the purpose of those lines (left over from debugging? someone wanted to create an assertion but did not finish it?). They are not really bugs, since they just don't have any impact on whether the example will fail or pass (as longs as the methods they refer to are there). But besides that, those lines are just useless code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any special behavior.  I think you've found errors in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because there's no assertion, only a comparison:

`@numbers.permutation(9).entries.size == 0`

It would need to be written as:

`@numbers.permutation(9).entries.size.should == 0`

Or using the newer RSpec syntax:

`expect(@numbers.permutation(9).entries.size).to eq(0)`